# How should I schedule the sleep and feeding pattern of my infant so that he gets enough feed when I am at home?

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding, working-parents

I am a working person.

After my child is 3 months old, I will continue to go to my job from morning 7:00 till evening 18:00.

I will be coming home at around 14:00 to breastfeed for about half an hour.
So, I can breastfeed only between evening 18:00 to morning 7:00 and half an hour during the day.

Assuming I wish to avoid using the pumps, how should I schedule the infant's sleeping pattern so that I can feed him as much as I can when I am at home such he doesn't feel much hungry during my absence?

Comment: Who will take care of the baby while you're at work? How will the baby be fed while you're at work?

Comment: Well, we'll be having a maid servant around. Will it be problematic if we feed him the formula during the day? @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun

Comment: @AnishaKaul It would be ok. I know several families who combined breast milk with formula (either because they weren't producing enough or because of work schedule). To be extra-safe you could ask your doctor or a trusted nutritionist to advise you on what would be the best way to do it.

Comment: There is no way you can let your baby go unfed for 7 hours during the day, that's just insane! Your baby needs food every 2.5-3 hours to grow and thrive. If you don't want to pump, you need to supplement with formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some people work on switching day and night patterns for the baby, so there is lots of being awake and eating while mum is home, and mostly sleeping and not feeding while mum is away. This has its own downsides, of course, but it is something that works for some people.

More realistically, you are probably going to use bottles in the daytime, whether they have formula or pumped milk in them. Do not start the bottles too soon. Wait until a week or two before you go back to work. Nipple confusion is a real thing that can lead the baby to reject the breast for the bottle. The longer you wait the more likely it is the baby can switch between the two.

It is probably a good idea to keep the baby up a little later at night once you start work. You might even have a normal wakeup of 9 or 10 am, and you stop by and wake the baby for the 7am feed, then go. While this won't give you peaceful evenings like the families who put the baby to bed at 7pm, it will give you one or two more nursings every evening and little less pressure on you to get your mothering into a short period of time before it is baby's bedtime.

Whether you pump or use formula is a personal decision. It can be hard to find a place to pump at work, and hard to bring the pumped milk home each evening. I would put that decision off until the baby has actually arrived and you get an idea for how tired you are and how easy you find nursing. If you drop all the daytime feeds at 3 months and don't pump, using formula, your supply might adjust or it might not. Pumping ensures your supply will continue. (BTW, don't confuse the nursing-got-shorter-and-I-don't-swell-and-feel-sore-when-it's-feeding-time phenomenon with losing your supply. At about 4 months most of the physical issues some women get in early nursing go away, and the baby gets really efficient at getting milk out, and sadly some women think this means they're losing their supply.)

If you do intend to pump about half your baby's milk, get a serious plug-in pump with good power. Battery pumps are for using on occasional outings without the baby, and are as much about relieving pressure and keeping up supply as they are about getting milk. You can rent plug in pumps on pretty short notice, but look into it now to make sure you know how to get one.

Comment: `This has its own downsides, of course,` What are its downsides?

Comment: having the baby awake for much of the night means you will be awake for much of the night, and you need to sleep too.

Comment: `Do not start the bottles too soon. Wait until a week or two before you go back to work.` I'll be going to work after 3 months. Will that be enough?

Comment: Depends on your baby. For some, they switch back and forth from birth. But others, once they have a bottle, they won't nurse again. There's no guarantee but generally, the older the baby was when they first had a bottle, the more likely they continued to nurse as well.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the fact that newborn babies eat every 2 or 3 hours and babies fed on breast milk tend to get hungry sooner than those fed on milk formula it would be a good idea to have a plan on how to keep the baby fed while you're at work. Surely, one meal between 7am and 6pm would not be enough.

You should seriously consider using the pumps or a milk formula so the baby can have his/her meals whenever he/she's hungry.

Comment: but a 3 month old baby is not the same as a newborn baby

Comment: @Chrys It applies too, since 3 month old breast fed babies eat a few ounces every 2, 3, maybe 4 hours.